# How to read a value of an enum which associates with a custom type in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust

I have an implementation in Rust as follows. In the main function, I am reading a value in `SalaryRange` enum and this will display `High("So High")`.

```
// This can be a complex type, just using string for the question 
type SRange = String;
type SalEnu = SalaryRange<SRange>;

struct User<SRange> {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    sign_in_count: u64,
    active: bool,
    income: Income<SRange>,
}

struct Income<SRange> {
    salary_range: SalaryRange<SRange>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum SalaryRange<SRange> {
    Low(SRange),
    Mid(SRange),
    High(SRange),
}

fn main() {
    let user1 = User {
        email: String::from("test@email.com"),
        username: String::from("test_name"),
        active: true,
        sign_in_count: 1,
        income: Income {
            salary_range: (
                SalaryRange::High("So High")
            )
        },
    };
    let mut srange: SalaryRange<&str> = user1.income.salary_range;
    println!("{:?}", srange);
}
```

Link for this [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e1c959b8c5d44ea515fd716e02c7d82) can be found here.

Just wanted to know if there is a possibility to read and print the value in that enum as `println!("{:?}", srange::High);`, just to print out the string value? 
I only want to print the value `So High`.

If I use `srange::High` This will throw an error saying

```
      println!("{:?}", srange::High);
|                      ^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `srange`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What did you intend `println!("{:?}", srange::High);` to output?

Comment: @PeterHall Updated only wanted to print  `So High`.

Comment: I know this isn't what you are asking about, but you have some very suspicious variable naming which could cause confusion. In `SalaryRange<SRange>`, `SRange` is a type _variable_. But it is named the same as an alias you have made for the `String`. In my answer, I renamed that to `S` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @PeterHall Yep, sorry for the confusion, the real type of it is a complex one, added String only for the example, Thanks

Comment: The String isn't the problem. When you look at the definition, you could mistakenly think that the type of data held by `Salary::Low` is `SRange`. But actually the type could be whatever type you decide. From another perspective, the `SRange` *type variable* is shadowing the `SRange` *concrete type*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a method on your enum to extract the value:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum SalaryRange<S> {
    Low(S),
    Mid(S),
    High(S),
}

impl<S> SalaryRange<S> {
    fn value(&self) -> &S {
        match self {
            SalaryRange::Low(value) => value,
            SalaryRange::Mid(value) => value,
            SalaryRange::High(value) => value,
        }
    }
}
```

```
println!("{:?}", srange.value());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pattern match `srange` with the [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) syntax.

```
if let SalaryRange::High(s) = srange {
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

will print "so high".

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question has been opened, but I would like to complete [Peter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54866005/10566644) answer.

There is a more idiomatic way to achieve what you want. Just implement the [`std::fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait to your enum as following:

```rust
pub enum SalaryRange {
    LOW(String),
    MID(String),
    HIGH(String),
}

impl std::fmt::Display for SalaryRange {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let content = match self {
            SalaryRange::LOW(content) => content,
            SalaryRange::MID(content) => content,
            SalaryRange::HIGH(content) => content,
        };

        write!(f, "{}", content)
    }
}
```

The [`std::fmt::Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) trait allows you to display the content held by your enum value like this:

```rust
let salary_range = SalaryRange::HIGH("So high".to_string());
println!("{}", salary_range);
// outputs: "So high"
```

This should work with any type.

Playground to test it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eaea33a955dc9dcd81a4b96ec22d82bd

Comment: This is about pattern matching , not about printing

Comment: @0x12 I might had misunderstood this part then: "Just wanted to know if there is a possibility to read and print the value in that enum as println!("{:?}", srange::High);, just to print out the string value? I only want to print the value So High."